# Magento2 products count suddenly getting reduce in category pages

Tags: magento, indexing, magento2

I'm working on Magento 2.3.6 EE version with 68 stores and around 10K products.

Sometimes the products on the category reduce without any reason and automatically get appear again in a few minutes.

Has anyone faced an issue like this before? I assume this is something with indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the cache on your site. You can run these two commands one by one

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Magento has provided a patch for this issue
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050636011-MDVA-30977-missing-products-from-categories-indexing-related

Comment: Hope this Magento patch can help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you can run ssh command, you can try below command to fix immediately

```html
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

For long term, you need go to System->Index Management change index mode to update by schedule if not being set like this